# Is a gaming computer important for playing games?

Tags: pc

If one wished to play video games on PC, would they require a gaming PC or a typical PC will do?

Comment: Please define what are "gaming PC" and "typical PC" and tell us which exactly games. The crappiest PC in the world will be capable to run *some* games (e.g. MUDs) and at the same time you can now make a game what require more than the best gaming system is capable.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, a gaming PC is just a moniker. It has no established description. Also, you don't necessarily need a "gaming PC" to play video games. Depending on multiple factors, your PC might or might not be a good system.

- For online competitive games, you need a fast internet. If you don't have one, the most expensive of gaming computers won't be able to give you a good experience.
- A lot of AAA titles include a high level of lifelike effects and are built to mirror realism. These effects need a lot of GPU power. As a result, any PC with an older GPU cannot run newer AAA titles smoothly.
- A minimum amount of RAM is required for a game to function well. The RAM size dictates how much volatile information can be stored to be passed to the GPU's VRAM while a game is running. Even if your PC has the best GPU and CPU but a low RAM size that is less than what a game requires (or the combination of all apps require including system functions and any streaming or typical apps that are also running), then the game will be exceptionally slow.

In fact, a lot of components are specific to a type of game or genre of game. For some games, the CPU is a better priority while for others, it can be the GPU, and for most recent AAA titles, it's both. Read more about CPU vs. GPU vs. RAM [here](https://spearblade.com/general/gpu-cpu-ram/).

Comment: I would argue significant storage space is needed nowadays.  Some games, such as Call of Duty Modern Warfare, are well over 200Gb in size.  I can't even fit it on any of my SSDs since they are too small.  This seems to be a common trend for newer games, taking up large amounts of space.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on *what kind of games* you want to play and what you mean by "gaming PC" and "typical PC". I will therefore have to make some assumptions.

A gaming PC tends to refer to a PC which has sufficient power to run graphically-demanding games. These tend to be FPS games but they can be other titles too. A gaming PC will normally have a dedicated graphics card, a PSU which has sufficient power to run said card with the rest of the system at least at 90% load, and a processor with multiple cores [four absolute minimum] and a decent amount of RAM - minimum 8GB. It should also, ideally, have a dedicated sound card. A gaming PC is generally a lot more expensive to purchase components for. Gaming PCs tend to be built manually by gamers, though custom or pre-built gaming PCs do exist too.

Business desktop PCs - or a "typical PC", one would imagine - can run simple graphical games, but even games which appear graphically simple can be deceptively demanding on a system e.g. Minecraft. There are also many games, e.g. Witcher 3, Skyrim Special Edition, Shadow of the Tomb Raider etc which one would need to run on a high-powered gaming PC and which would definitely not run on a desktop PC with onboard graphics. Consider running Cyberpunk 2077 on a standard desktop "typical PC" - it would be impossible.

Therefore it really depends on **what games you want to play**. If you are casually playing simple puzzle games or games released over fifteen years ago, a modern desktop PC could probably handle most of them. Probably all of them if they are 20 years old. However, if you are planning to play up-to-date or graphically-demanding games, you would definitely need a "gaming PC".

PS: I personally have a "gaming PC" but it is really on the edge of what one could consider a gaming PC these days. Its CPU is ten years ago and its GPU is 12 years old. It can play almost anything released in the 2000s and most games released in the 2010s. However, if I ran it as is for another ten years I would be hard pressed to call it a gaming PC any longer. I would just call it a "typical" PC.

**TLDR;** If you want to play video games on a PC then yes, you would need a "gaming PC" since it's fair to assume you would want to play modern games without limitation, which a "typical PC" will not be able to handle.

Comment: Yeah the good old meme of 'I SPENT 3K ON THIS BABY!' Plays Among us and Fall Guys. Really, look, if you want to play the latest Triple-As at 60FPS and the top graphic settings, then you will need the 3k monster. But really, if you want to play the latest games but not with the flashy 60FPS and top graphics, a good 1k to 1.5k PC could last you for years. If you will only play Fall Guys and Among Us and League of Legends, a basic 500$ tower could work.

Comment: A dedicated sound card is not needed.  What is needed, at least for FPS games is a good headset, which nowadays usually connect via USB.  For most other purposes, onboard sound is still sufficient, and has been for more than a decade.  Discrete sound cards are decidedly niche these days, to the point that they're really only useful for audio editing and mastering.

Comment: @MBraedley thanks for the info - I have a dedicated sound card which I love, since I use Linux and it needs no tweaks to sound great. Maybe I would notice the difference between the X-Fi and onboard? I don't know. But I did use the word "ideally" to describe the sound card situation, and I acknowledge that for a lot of people one will not be necessary,

Comment: @Fredy31 Even a 1.5K computer (assuming current components) could run graphically intense games at 1440p/144hz. A 3K monster PC is realistically less of a general gaming machine and more suitable as a machine you also use for video editing and 3D modeling. For comparison: Nvidia's strongest card of the moment, the 1500 USD RTX 3090, is meant for 8K gaming at 60 FPS.

Comment: Yeah, but for how long, that is the question.  Especially now, in the next year the graphics intensiveness will jump because of the new console generation.